# In SSRS 2008 matrix, header freeze is not working when deployed

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have added a matrix in SSRS report and I want to freeze its headers.

Listed below are the methods I tried, these methods are the popular solutions listed in internet for similar type of issues, but both of them are not working.

Method 1:- in Tablix Properties.
under Row Headers or Column Headers, select Header should remain visible while scrolling. This method works in MS Visual Studio 2008 while previewing but when deployed it is not working

Method 2: static tablix member method- As this is a matrix and not a table, there is no static member at the top where I want to freeze in the row group, so cant do the advanced mode-->static tablix member method

Please help

Comment: I only got the freeze to work in the visual studio report viewer and when exporting to excel. I never saw the freeze in browsers.

Comment: What browser are you using to view the deployed report? I think this only worked in IE when I tried this in the past.

Comment: I tried to use browsers IE and chrome. It is not working in both